# How to get an instance of a loaded library in codeigniter

Tags: php, codeigniter

I am trying to get an instance of a loaded library in codeigniter, but am having difficulty. I have in my controller:

```
$arguments=array('login'=>'***','pass'=>'***');  ;                   
$this->load->library('mailer', $arguments);
```

My constructors first line looks like:

```
public function __construct($arr)
```

This appears to work.

When I add: the next line in my controller:

```
$phpmail = new Mailer;
```

I get the following:

```
Severity: Warning

Message: Missing argument 1 for Mailer::__construct(),
```

How can I get a new instance of this library in my controller?

Thanks in advance,

Bill

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The CI library loader adds an instance of the library directly to the current controller object.  After loading the `mailer` library, you can access an instance of it as `$this->mailer`.

Comment: May I ask how we can get the instance back in order to store it to an array for example? 

[inside the controller] 


$this->someclass; 


gives the current instance every time? 


cause I did the following with diffrent $params for each on but what I got as a result was the first object not two diffrent: 


$this->load->library('SomeClass', $params); 


print_r($this->someclass); 


$this->load->library('SomeClass', $params); 


print_r($this->someclass);